# Do you have to sacrifice a transformed creature put into play via Through the Breach?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-double-faced-cards, mtg-modern

If I put [Thing in the Ice](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bThing%20in%20the%20Ice%5d) into play via [Through the Breach](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bThrough%20the%20Breach%5d), and it transforms during my turn, do I have to sacrifice [Awoken Horror](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAwoken%20Horror%5d) at the beginning of the next end step?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes.**

From the [Comprehensive Rules](http://media.wizards.com/2018/downloads/MagicCompRules%2020180119.pdf):

> 711.12. When a double-faced permanent transforms, it doesn’t become a new object. **Any effects that applied to that permanent will continue
>   to apply to it after it transforms.** *Example: An effect gives Village
>   Ironsmith (the front face of a double-faced card) +2/+2 until end of
>   turn and then Village Ironsmith transforms into Ironfang. Ironfang
>   will continue to get +2/+2 until end of turn.*

Answer (score 7):

### Yes.

A transformed creature is the same creature it was before. Auras don't fall off and temporary effects don't go away.

Now, "exile and return transformed" cards leave play, so they will enter as new objects.